error in anchor test
Found a 'test' script in the Anchor.toml. Running it as a test suite!
Running test suite: "/home/emperor/solana-txn-mod1/hello-solana/Anchor.toml"
Usage Error: The nearest package directory (/home/emperor/solana-txn-mod1/hello-solana) doesn't seem to be part of the project declared in /home/emperor.

If /home/emperor isn't intended to be a project, remove any yarn.lock and/or package.json file there.
If /home/emperor is intended to be a project, it might be that you forgot to list solana-txn-mod1/hello-solana in its workspace configuration.
Finally, if /home/emperor is fine and you intend solana-txn-mod1/hello-solana to be treated as a completely separate project (not even a workspace), create an empty yarn.lock file in it.

$ yarn run [--inspect] [--inspect-brk] [-T,--top-level] [-B,--binaries-only] [--require #0]  ...
